# How to create month partitions, in given table structure

Tags: mysql

How to create Month partitions

```
CREATE TABLE `now_articles` (
  `articleId` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title_md5` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `urltoImage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `publishedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_source_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categoryOrder` enum('0','1','-1') DEFAULT '0',
  `homeOrder` enum('0','1','-1') DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`articleId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title_md5` (`title_md5`),
  KEY `categories` (`categories`),
  KEY `source` (`source`),
  KEY `publishedAt` (`publishedAt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "partition" here?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Are you sure that you want month partitions? Are some months typically quieter than other months?

Comment: you want month wise table for articles right ? Also with month in partitions ?

Comment: You could use one of the examples here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-types.html

Comment: alter table now_articles add partition by hash(MONTH(publishedAt))    error:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by hash(MONTH(publishedAt))' at line 1

Comment: P.Salmon : mysql version is 5.6.33

Comment: Yes i checked ..

Comment: Try to remove the `ADD` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 5.6 but in 5.7 a correct syntax for the alter table is

alter table now_articles
PARTITION BY HASH( month(publishedat) )
    PARTITIONS 12;

but when you run this you will get two errors

ERROR 1503 (HY000): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
ERROR 1503 (HY000): A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

which means you have to amend your primary and unique key to include publishedat.

Answer (score 0):

You can Rename table every month through con job using any scripting language PHP or Python on every end of month.

After that create same table with given structure.
I hope it may help you.